# How to fix error with Russian encoding in maven?

Tags: java, maven, encoding, character-encoding

I use pattern with Russian symbols(alphabet) and maven decode this with error

In original pattern look like this `#[\w]+|#[А-я,ё,\d,_]+`, but in error it looks like that:
 `#[\w]+|#[Р?-С?,С?,\d,_]+`

Full text of error:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 12
#[\w]+|#[Р?-С?,С?,\d,_]+
               ^
```

**UPD**

In properties of project i have that `<project.build.sourceEncoding>windows-1251</project.build.sourceEncoding>`, and in maven-compiler-plugin I add `<encoding>windows-1251</encoding>`. Nothing not change

Comment: Why not use UTF-8?

Comment: @Slaw I don't know jow and why it works, but it works. Write this like a asnwer

Comment: I would write it as an answer, if I knew for sure why it made a difference myself. As [windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) seems meant for languages like Russian, my guess is it's related to file encoding. Most IDEs I've used automatically save Java source files using UTF-8. The property of the compiler plugin is the value of the `-encoding` option for `javac`. This leads to you saving the source files in UTF-8 but the compiler reading them as windows-1251. If those two are not one-to-one compatible regarding the characters used, there will be translation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like Maven might be using the wrong character encoding to read your source files. You can specify the correct encoding using the [project.build.sourceEncoding](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/encoding.html) property, or with the [encoding](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#encoding) parameter of the compiler plugin.

Comment: I have already change encoding to <project.build.sourceEncoding>windows-1251</project.build.sourceEncoding>, but thats didnt help me